# apply template in xslt is not working

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xsl transform. I don't know why the code is not going in template. I think its problem of namespace.

Here is my code. XSL Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1 .0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:conv="HSW.FileConvertor" exclude-result-prefixes="conv" xmlns:x="http://abcd.net/abcd/ws/incomingPayments/dto">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;PHONE;LANGUAGE;SMS_OPS_TYPE;CONTRACT_CODE;AMOUNT;DATE;DPD&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/x:incomingPayments/x:incomingPayment" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:incomingPayment">
    <xsl:if test="x:paymentChannel='DO_2013'">
        <xsl:variable name="Contract_code" select="x:contractNumber"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Amount" select="x:amount/x:moneyValue"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="Contract_search">
            <xsl:with-param name="Contract_code" select="$Contract_code"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="Amount" select="$Amount"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="Contract_search">
    <xsl:param name="Contract_code"/>
    <xsl:param name="Amount"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$Contract_code"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'  '"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$Amount"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and here is my xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hsIncomingPaymentsFile xmlns="http://abcd.net/abcd/ws/incomingPayments/dto">
<incomingPayments>
    <incomingPayment>
        <depositDate>2014-08-11</depositDate>
        <paymentChannel>DO_2013</paymentChannel>
        <contractNumber>3300867119</contractNumber><!-- extracting this tag -->
        <transactionDate>2014-08-11</transactionDate>
        <amount>
            <moneyValue>4850</moneyValue><!-- extracting this tag -->
            <currency>INR</currency>
        </amount>
        <transactionNumber/>
        <paymentType>PFC</paymentType>
    </incomingPayment>
<!-- second record -->
    <incomingPayment>
        <depositDate>2014-08-11</depositDate>
        <paymentChannel>DO_2013</paymentChannel>
        <contractNumber>3300861289</contractNumber><!-- extracting this tag -->
        <transactionDate>2014-08-11</transactionDate>
        <amount>
            <moneyValue>960</moneyValue><!-- extracting this tag -->
            <currency>INR</currency>
        </amount>
        <transactionNumber/>
        <paymentType>PFC</paymentType>
    </incomingPayment>
</incomingPayments>
</hsIncomingPaymentsFile >
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with this line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/x:incomingPayments/x:incomingPayment" />
```

You have start off the expression with a forward slash `/` which represents the document node (which is the parent level to the root element in the XML). This means it is expecting the root element to be `x:incomingPayments` which it isn't. Your root node is `x:hsIncomingPaymentsFile`.

Try this instead:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="x:hsIncomingPaymentsFile/x:incomingPayments/x:incomingPayment" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:conv="HSW.FileConvertor" exclude-result-prefixes="conv" xmlns:x="http://abcd.net/abcd/ws/incomingPayments/dto">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;PHONE;LANGUAGE;SMS_OPS_TYPE;CONTRACT_CODE;AMOUNT;DATE;DPD&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="x:hsIncomingPaymentsFile/x:incomingPayments/x:incomingPayment" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:incomingPayment">
    <xsl:if test="x:paymentChannel='DO_2013'">
        <xsl:variable name="Contract_code" select="x:contractNumber"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Amount" select="x:amount/x:moneyValue"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="Contract_search">
            <xsl:with-param name="Contract_code" select="$Contract_code"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="Amount" select="$Amount"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Contract_search">
    <xsl:param name="Contract_code"/>
    <xsl:param name="Amount"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$Contract_code"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'  '"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$Amount"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces this following output

```
PHONE;LANGUAGE;SMS_OPS_TYPE;CONTRACT_CODE;AMOUNT;DATE;DPD
3300867119  4850
3300861289  960
```

Go to http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaES/1 to see this in action

Comment: This should go into the template, although I can't say if it fully "works" or not because you haven't said what output you expect. As an demonstration though, check out http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaES/1 which shows some output being produced by the template.

Comment: I even tried this code on online formatter but without namespace and it gave the required result

Comment: I've expanded my answer with a full working sample, if it helps.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with the jar in my system

Comment: Double-check your XML is what you expect. If you say it is working without namespaces, maybe your actual XML is really missing them, or maybe it has a namespace prefix which is not being used.

Comment: @DilpreetJuneja This answer is helpful and correct. You should _accept_ it (mark the tick on the left so that it appears in green).